# Why does my number input put an "<" in front of my numbers?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

So the problem is that i have a input type number just like any other regular input type number, but for some reason that am not able to understand it put a "<" sign in front of my numbers.

```
<div class="child">
          <div class="label-form">

            <label for="numC">Numero de Contrato:</label>

          </div>
          <?php while($vector2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) { ?>
          <div class="input">
                  <?php echo $vector2[0]+1;?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="NumeroContrato" value="<?php echo $vector2[0]+1;?>">
          </div>
      </div>
        <?php } ?>

     <div class="child">   

          <div class="label-form">
              <label for="nMota">Numero da mota</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="number"  id="nMota" name="nMota" placeholder="Bike Number" required>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Its the "nMota" input; for example if i put a 1 it receive the information as <1 if i put a 7 it put <7. I have no idea why.

Comment: Have you looked at what is being sent to the server? Also there’s no server side code not information on how this is sent there to determine what could be wrong. Normal form with get/post? AJAX?

Comment: Its with POST "$NumeroMota = $_POST['nMota'];" the server receive "<7" and doesnt pass to the db because its not valid. " $sql4 = "UPDATE bikes SET Combustivel = '$Combustivel', WHERE NumeroMota = '$NumeroMota'"; "

Comment: `UPDATE bikes SET Combustivel = '$Combustivel', WHERE ` is that really the code you used? there's a syntax error in it.

Comment: Can you put a `print_r($_POST); exit;` at the top of the processing page and then share with us the resulting array?

Comment: Check your first <?php, have seen it before when someone accidentally puts <<?php and that causes it